# Why is the Quantum Electrodynamic Hamiltonian complex?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, momentum, hamiltonian, complex-numbers

For reference, this is from Shankar's QM book, with the Hamiltonian
$$H=\frac{1}{2m}\left(\textbf{P}\cdot\textbf{P}-\frac{q}{c}\textbf{P}\cdot\textbf{A}-\frac{q}{c}\textbf{A}\cdot\textbf{P}+\frac{q^2}{c^2}\textbf{A}\cdot\textbf{A}\right)$$
and the exact quote is "If the problem involves a magnetic field, the Hamiltonian is no longer real in the coordinate basis".

Is the Hamiltonian no longer real in the coordinate basis because $\textbf{A}$ and $\textbf{P}$ do not commute, and so the conjugate will be different?

Comment: Why would P and A commute?

Comment: thanks for pointing that out.  It's a typo which has been fixed.  A and P do not commute.

Comment: What makes you think it is "no longer real"? It must be self-adjoint and bounded from below.

Comment: It says in the book that if the "If the problem involves a magnetic field, the Hamiltonian is no longer real in the coordinate basis".  If you have the book it's on the bottom of p.177.

Comment: @Redcrazyguy Have you considered how $\mathbf{P}$ and $\mathbf{A}$ are represented in the coordinate basis?

Answer (score 0):

The Hamiltonian is *Hermitian* in that it equals its own *adjoint*: $H = H^\dagger$. In a matrix representation, the adjoint is the *conjugate transpose*, not simply the conjugate. Thus, a Hermitian operator can be represented by a matrix that is neither real nor symmetric, as long as conjugating and transposing *together* return the original matrix.

A simple example of a nonreal Hermitian operator is the momentum operator in the position basis, $\mathbf{P} = -i \hbar \boldsymbol{\nabla}$. Applying this to a real function generally returns a nonreal function; likewise for the Hamiltonian in the question. However, being Hermitian, these operators always have real *eigenvalues*.